# Is it good to use Wait cursor in websites?

Tags: php, asp.net, javascript, cursor

Is it good to use Wait cursor in websites? On heavy loading pages I don't generally see it used with websites. (please share some if you have seen any.)

If I implement the below code, will it be compatible with the current browsers?

```
function doHourglass()
{
  document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
}
```

and

```
<form runat="server" onsubmit="return setHourglass();">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use cursor styles all the time to show where/when certain actions are available.

Users are familiar with the wait cursor, so feel free to use it in your (web)application.

It is compatible with "all major browsers" as explained in [CSS2 - Cursor Styles](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html)

Answer (score 15):

Wait cursor will be confusing since usually it's OS-related, I'd prefer to have some kind of "loading now" in your own web page (which is widely used)

Answer (score 5):

The wait cursor may be perceived as related to the browser rather than the website specifically - I would recommend an animation specific to the web page.

Comment: Animations are neat.  I upvoted Soufiane instead of this answer simply because some browsers like IE7 stop animated GIFs from functioning during postback.  Animations are rendered useless.

Answer (score 2):

The "wait cursor" in a website is, in my experience, the little AJAX swirly.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the operating system's default "wait" cursor then it may confuse the user into thinking they're waiting for their hardware to finish an operation rather than the web page.

If you don't want a user to submit a form twice whilst waiting for a script to process, then you could modify your JavaScript function to either disable the submit button on click, or add a  to your page containing the often used animated circle icon and a loading message to communicate to the user.